# Fitting harmonic model in R of the form a*sin(b*x+c)

Tags: r

In my time series modeling class, we were taught to model harmonic patterns in time series by creating several SINE and COSINE terms at different frequencies, and then keeping the ones that were significant.

However, now I would like to find the best fit model of the form `a*sin(b*x+c)`, and don't know where to start.

Comment: Folks here tend to be more responsive if you demonstrate that you've at least tried to solve this yourself. Then you can repost your question with your attempt and a reproducible example. With those relatively modest steps, you'd be amazed at the help you'll find. Right now this reads like "please do my work for me". Also check out ?nls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I support the comment of boshek, I just played around for fun:

```
# As you dont provide any data, here some simulated data:
set.seed(1)
x <- seq(0, 10, length = 100)
y <- sin(2*x + 5) + rnorm(100, sd=0.5)
y_clean <- sin(2*x + 5)

# Plot of the noised data (y) and the noiseless line (y_clean) which you want to approximate through your model:
plot(x, y, ylim = c(-2,3))
lines(x,y_clean, col = "green")

# Model estimation and adding of the fitted values to the previous plot:
model <- nls(y~a*sin(b*x+c), start = list(a=1,b=1.5, c=1),control = list(maxiter = 500))
lines(x, fitted(model), col = "red")

legend("topright", col=c("green", "red"), legend = c("\"true\" curve", "fitted line"), bty = "n", lty = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: how would you use selfstart here? My data is very complicated and I am getting some errors because my estimates aren't good enough. I know Logiss is a self-start function but can a similar function be used here?

Comment: Can use the nls2 package to get starting values.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, could you explain how? It appears to me that nls2 is simply nls with the addition of the "brute force" algorithm.

Comment: There are examples in the help file for `nls2`